# What is PayPal API for when accepting payments in my website thru a button? Do I need to use API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm in the process of developing a feature to accept payments in my website, and I already did it using a paypal button and IPN (a PHP listener to process data to a DB once the payment is completed, this one actually https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php, properly customized).

I never touched PayPal API and I wonder if I am missing something... I'm kind of new to this kind of development and I want to be sure I'm doing it right and not missing any obvious thing which might compromise the security of the payment or whatever... I already tested things in Sandbox and everything works as expected, but I am concerned about the API and I see many people using it...

So, am I missing anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've done is accurate and will work just fine so long as it's suiting your needs.

One potential security risk would be if you are not using a hosted button.  Did you choose to "Save this button at PayPal" when you created the button?  If so, you should see a hosted_button_id included in the HTML for the button.  In this case it's protected.

If the button code includes individual parameters for things like item_name, amount, etc. then that code could be adjusted by people in their browser and then the button could be submitted with different pricing, for example.

You could check for this sort of thing in your IPN script and setup an automatic refund if the price doesn't match your database, but I generally try to avoid that sort of thing.

I prefer using the Express Checkout API instead.  If you were comfortable getting IPN working with PHP then you should be plenty comfortable using this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) to integrate Express Checkout.

The three calls you'll need to work with are SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

[This documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/) will cover the general steps and where those calls come into play, and that library will make each of those calls very simple for you.

Express Checkout will eliminate any potential adjustments users could make to code (because they won't be able get to the code at all unlike HTML) and it also has more advanced features and options that PayPal Standard does not have.  Most importantly, the ability to force the "guest checkout" experience so that non-PayPal account holders can easily checkout using a credit card without any confusion.

They can do it with PayPal Standard, too, but depending on cookies set in their browser it may make the guest checkout option tough to find.  Express Checkout makes it very prominent at all times, and generally results in increased checkout conversion rates.